# cant get text boxes to fill a panel

Tags: css, asp.net

so i have this bit of asp here:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlNavigator" CssClass="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body" style="width:100%">

        <div style="display:inline-block" >

            <br /><br />
            <div class="container" style="display:inline-block">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="33%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text=" ***Teacher Training, CPD, Mentor Training***">

                </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="33%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="***Sports Science, steps, FMS facilitator***">

                </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="33%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="***Professional Development, Consultant***">

                </asp:TextBox>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>



</asp:Panel>
```

and basically they aren't filling up the entire panel,they're only reaching about half way then starting a new line underneath, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap `.css` adds a pixel `::before` and `::after` the elements so the combined width of the three `textarea`s exceeds 100%.

**1st solution**: decrease the width by 1%

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="32%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="***Sports Science, steps, FMS facilitator***">
</asp:TextBox>
```

**2nd solution**: use bootstrap grid system to control layout

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlNavigator" CssClass="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <%-- style="width:100%">--%>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <%-- style="display:inline-block" >--%>
            <%--            <br /><br />--%>
            <div class="row">
                <%-- style="display:inline-block">--%>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text=" ***Teacher Training, CPD, Mentor Training***">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="***Sports Science, steps, FMS facilitator***">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="***Professional Development, Consultant***">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```